# Javascript access to property of undefined

Tags: javascript, object

In PHP I can set variable to be `$arr['test1'][0]['test2']`

But in JavaScript there are no associative arrays but objects. How can I make situation where I have JSON objects that are different always and I want to store fields if there exists, and store `null` if not like in PHP.

```
test1 = temp.test1[0].test
```

Gives me error - `cannot access property test of undefined`.

I know that there is workaround for this that I can check if there is property, but I have many different objects, and there are deeply nested, so I need solution where it is automatic, if whole nested property exist store, if not (or if it is property of undefined) store `null`.

Comment: why do you need to do that?

Comment: Because i am listening for data that can have different properties, and i have to override them in database for that object but field names are different. For example, if score1 fields is empyy on data.scores[0].score then score1 is null in database untill we have that thata in object, and that i have for 100 types of potential properties.